# Getting 404 when hitting OSGi WAB servlet deployed on JBoss AS7

Tags: osgi, jboss7.x, embedded-jetty

I am very new to OSGi.I am doing a POC for my project. I am able to develop normal OSGi bundles,deploy them on JBoss AS 7 platform, consume other bundle's services etc. But when it comes to the web part I'm stuck. I wanted to create a web app bundle for my POC. I created a normal web app with just one servlet ( with url-mapping /test in web.xml). And below is my MANIFEST file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-ClassPath: .,WEB-INF/classes/
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestWab
Export-Package: com.ctl.osgi.servlets
Web-ContextPath: /TestWab
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework,javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http
```

But when I hit the URL `http://localhost:8080/TestWab/test` its giving me a 404 error. I followed the below link when creating the app and I had followed it religiously. Most of the links for OSGi WAB follows the same process.

link : https://community.jboss.org/message/647106

Even the fully functional sample application war in the above link produces the same result for me (a 404 error!!). So I believe there is something wrong with configuration/setup rather than code. Could some one please throw some light on this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: The MANIFEST looks fine. Maybe you didn't configure JBoss correctly?

Comment: Thanks @Neil for the response.I have done only this configuration change <code><property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">3</property></code>. And my stand alone OSGi bundles are working fine. Is there any special configuration required for WABs?

Answer (score 0):

I have started a [discussion thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/202836) on JBoss Community for this.

As per the replies OSGi WABs can be deployed in [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/647106) way (described by David) only for JBoss AS 7.0. For other versions you need to do some other configuration tweaks.Not ready with a solution yet, just following the thread hoping I will get soon.